# How to avoid segmentation fault in C when the array is defined?

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I have an array `A1[ ]={1,0,1,1,..'X',0,1,'X',.1,0...}`, as big as 10 Megas of binary integers and some 'X' values (taken as the ASCII integer value), I am thinking to use `malloc` but I already have the array defined (I am just copy and paste the values before running my code). Any other suggestions on how to avoid ***segmentation fault***? So far this the error that I am geting :(.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    //int A[]={'x','x',1,0,'x',0,'x',1,1,1,...};//up to 10M values
    int A[]={0,'x',1,'x',1,0,'x',0,'x','x',1,'x',0,'x','x','x','x','x','x',0};
    int j;

    #define n (sizeof(A)/sizeof(*A))     // bits
    printf("Patt size= %d\n",n);

    /*Code will be added here to make some calculations with A*/

    printf("A =");                       // show input
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        printf(" %d",A[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How we will know without code and proper problem description?

Comment: The must be some bug in the code you didn't show here. Please read this: [ask] and this: [mcve].

Comment: Remember the stack is limited. If this array is on the stack it is will cause stack overflow on most systems unless you increase the stack size.

Comment: Just to add proportions to Stack size limitations, on many systems the stack is limited to 2Mb or 4 Mb. Unless ou have a special system, 10Mb of data should be dynamically allocated and filled.

Comment: What you have posted isn't valid C (no type of `A`), but assuming that's just fantasy code and your *real* code is actually proper., if that really is a 10MB automatic variable in `main()`, that's very likely your problem and @drescherjm hit it spot-on. The most effortless step you can take is to move it outside of `main` or qualify it as `static`.

Comment: I believe that Windows has a default stack size of 1 MiB and Unix machines generally have a default stack size of 8 MiB.  Your outline code is missing the type, but even assuming it is `char`, you are blowing the stack.  You'll need to define and initialize the variable outside the `main()` function — or use dynamic memory allocation, but that leaves you with a major problem w.r.t the initializer.  Go with file static variable outside the function (or even a `static` variable inside the function).

Comment: There are a number of previous questions where there was similar code with similar consequence and similar prescriptions (`static`, or dynamic allocation).  Finding a canonical duplicate will be harder, though.

Comment: What is `s` in your code?

Comment: if you're on linux, you can `ulimit -s` to display the current per-thread stack size in kilobytes. Mine defaults (I haven't changed it) to 8192k == 8Mb, so 10+Mb would overflow my stack